# How to make a good node/connection network | Java

Tags: java, networking

I want to make a network of clients connected to each other. Basically a decentralized network and I'm not sure how to do that (They should be able to send data to each other). I tried a network of SSLServers + Sockets but I'm not sure if that works with the keystores.

So:

- Has anyone a suggestion how to do that?
- What would you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are asking about the architecture or technology but you may want to take a look at this:

As far as I know this kind of decentralized form of network is known as Peer-to-Peer network or P2P.

To be frank, the idea behind is to have a registry node to maintain the peer groups and other shared preferences of the network. The registry address is known by all clients (by a default setting), each of which tries to connect to on startup. After each client connected to registry, it tries to register itself and get the list of other available clients. Most of the time clients loosen their connection to the registry and only try to connect to them on demand (or in a periodic manner). When one client wants to download some file, it tries to get the list of available resources and the peers who shared a specific file.

Since in this kind of networks each node may get service from another nodes or serve other nodes, your code for the node may have both of the `ServerSocket` and `Socket` to support the idea. If you try to implement it in a native way you should deal with threads to maintain concurrent serving to other clients and getting service from other nodes.

In a high available P2P networks there are more than one registry nodes to maintain the skeleton of the network. Moreover, Every client may volunteer to play the registry roles to help the network remain available even in the total failure of the default registry nodes.

This kind of networks is based on a sharing attitude so when it launched it starts to grow day to day and after a portion of time you cannot simply shut it down by shutting down the first main skeleton of the network.

This is just an idea to start with, but as it grows you may want to add more complex features to have a robust and extendable network.

Here is a good tutorial to implement such networks:
https://www.javaworld.com/article/2071877/enterprise-java/peer-to-peer-applications-made-easy.html

Hope this help.